# How to return global variables

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, return

I'm writing a function that creates a graphics window, get points from the user and draws a line with those points in the window. Here is my code:

```
def setUp():
    w = GraphWin("Demo",500,500)
    return w
def userInput():
   x1, y1, x2, y2 = (eval(input("Enter 4 numbers: ")))
   return x1, y1, x2, y2

def displayLine(w,x1,y1,x2,y2):
    var = Line (point(x1, y1), Point(x2, y2))
    var.draw(w)  

def main():
    w = setUp()         
    userInput() 
    displayLine(w,x1,y1,x2,y2)  
main()
```

The error I am getting is `global name 'x1' is not defined`. The `x1` variable is defined in the `userInput()` function.

Answer (score 2):

Since you return 4 values in `userInput()`, you also want to expand them in the same scope right before you want to use it, so try something like this for your `main()`

```
def main():
    w = setUp()         
    x1, y1, x2, y2 = userInput() 
    displayLine(w,x1,y1,x2,y2)  
main()
```

Do note that your input method (eval) is definitely insecure since you are executing arbitrary user input, and user has to delimit their numbers specifically with commas which they are not informed of.

Answer (score 0):

The error is from the `main` method. `main` method does not have x1, y1, x2 or y2 declared in it. You should be doing

```
x1,y1,x2,y2 = userInput()
```

since `userInput()` returns these 4 values, while you are not accepting it in the `main` method.